# Sybase performance issue

Tags: scheduler, ase

Dears, I am planning to design database administration and maintenance tasks in Sybase ASE 15.0 , I will create stored procedure to perform these tasks, but I am wondering which way is more efficient to schedule jobs executing those stored procedures: by Sybase job scheduler or windows batch file that is executed according to windows scheduler task?

which choice is better and why
please advice

Answer (score 0):

Both can work just fine. But as a DBA, I would prefer the O/S scheduler as that gives me the ability to create scripts which is more convenient for some things (like moving files around) than having to do that in SQL.

Comment: Thank you Dear,  it still indefinite for me when should use one of these two choices.

Comment: Both are possible. Do you need to perform O/S commands? Then use batch files and external scheduler. Are you only executing SQL commands? Then you can use the built-in scheduler (thoogh it's also a matter of preference as well, I would prefer the external scheduler always)